# Is it possible to append to a DataFrame in one thread and perform operations on it in another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, buffer, python-multithreading

I'm building a script that receives data from a json/REST stream and then adds it to a database. I would like to build a buffer that collects the data from the stream and stores it until it is successfully inserted into the database.

The idea is that one thread would stream the data from the api into the dataframe and the other thread would try to submit the data into the database, removing the items from the dataframe once they are successfully inserted into the database.

I wrote the following code to test the concept - only problem is, it doesn't work!

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from itertools import count

# set delay
d=5

# add items to dataframe every few seconds
def appender():
    testdf = pd.DataFrame([])
    print('starting streamsim')
    for i in count():
        testdf1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(np.random.randint(0,25), 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
        testdf = testdf.append(testdf1)
        print('appended')
        print('len is now {0}'.format(len(testdf)))
        return testdf
        time.sleep(np.random.randint(0,5))

# combine the dfs, and operate on them
def dumper():
    print('starting dumpsim')
    while True:
        # check if there are values in the df
        if len(testdf.index) > 0:
            print('searching for values')
            for index, row in testdf.iterrows():
                if row['A'] < 10:
                    testdf.drop(index, inplace=True)
                    print('val dropped')
                else:
                    print('no vals found')

            # try to add rows to csv to simulate sql insert command
            for index, row in testdf.iterrows():
                # try to append to csv
                try:
                    with open('footest.csv', 'a') as f:
                        row.to_csv(f, mode= 'a', header=True)

                except:
                    print('append operation failed, skipping')
                    pass

                #if operation succeeds, drop the row
                else:
                    testdf.drop(index)
                    print('row dropped after success')

        if len(testdf.index) == 0:
            print('df is empty')
            pass

        time.sleep(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = appender).start()
    Thread(target = dumper).start()
```

Is there a way to make this work? Or are is a DataFrame 'locked' when one thread is working on it?